# active record stand alone: connection pooling

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Using `activerecord` outside rails, may I be confident all the connection drudgework is performed behind the curtains the same as inside rails?

In rails, `activerecord` does a great job establishing a connection pool and activating or closing connection as needed.

If I have a ruby daemon which calls a class file with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:production)
# more active_record tasks
```

can I assume on the following calls a connection from a pool is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, calling `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` will create a connection pool according to: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L842